# Is there a way to solo the fountain?

Tags: dota

As the title sugests. Is there any hero that could destroy the fountain by himself?
I have seen many teams together destroying the fountain but I was just wondering if a solo full-item build hero could.

How would I go about to do so?

Comment: I am talking about dota 1 ...

Comment: my bad, even dota though, its a team game why would you want to solo it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK first of all and easiest you can do it with **Sniper** lvl 7. His range is bigger than the fountain's range and you could easily do it as long as nobody is bothering you. There is no other ranged hero who can destroy it solo.

For melee heroes, the easiest way is to buy Vladimir's offering as it grants lifesteal from the fountain.

**Leoric** is best suited for this as your passive lifesteal works on the fountain so you won't even need Vladimir's — just damage. Though Vladimir's makes it very easy.

**Rikimaru** is probably in top three due to the 75% miss from smoke. Just get butterfly and some rapiers and you should do it. Attack until 30% then smoke: you will be almost full. Lather rinse repeat.

Last one which worked for me is **Faceless Void**, although he is a little harder as Chronosfere doesn't work on fountain. Passive skill for damage block and a butterfly, full rapier should do it.

This heroes worked for me, but I've also seen people succesfuly soloing it with heroes like **Ursa** or **Syllabear**(best full item build hero 12 item slots).

If you are not that selfish, bring on a Crystal Maiden with you. She can cube the fountain making it easy to kill with any hero. Another good support to kill the fountain would be Omniknight due to ultimate and heal.

Comment: You could've used the 'undelete' button instead of reposting your answer :)

Comment: Yeah. Well I got -1 for that for a good reason as it was a lousy answer so I thought putting a new fresh answer :)

Comment: @Fofole even lousy answers can be reversed with upvotes (and this happens all the time), and since you had a +1/-2 you still are a net positive for rep for the answer.

Comment: does mask of madness work vs fountain? if yes you can add huskar with a satanic+heal. he should probably be able to kill it if he has a few dmg items too.

Comment: @Wandang No. Vladimir's offering is the only item which grants lifesteal from fountain.

Answer (score 0):

Legion Commander with Butterfly, Heart of Tarrasque , Cuirass at a good level (when you have good stats and maxed press the attack). It's pretty common in pubs. Yeah I know this post is long gone, I just like replying though :)

Answer (score -1):

Adding the list heroes, I'm pretty sure Naix could do it years ago, charged with Satanics. I wish I could help more but I stopped playing WCIII Dota a 6.72f

Comment: Proof: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RzUW4d-kEB4

Answer (score -2):

Ursa, Leoric, Sniper and Syllaber are the only ones that can solo the fountain.

Answer (score -3):

Use Puck when destroying the fountain; he's a good tank. Just make good use of his first skill and you're good to go.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer?